# How to define a function to save a list to a same-name file

Tags: functional-style, files-and-directories

I want a convenient way to save lots of intermediate data lists into files, so that next time the files can be imported automatically to homonym list variables in the notebook, without having to evalutate some time-consuming intermediate steps again.

I can already use the following expression to export table1 to a file of same name.

```
table1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Export[ToString@((Trace@table1)[[1]]) <> ".dat", table1]
```

Then I define a table-saving function in this way:

```
tablesaveFunction := Export[ToString@((Trace@#)[[1]]) <> ".dat", #] &
tablesaveFunction[table1]
```

what I get is:

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
{}[[1]].dat
```

I guess the problem is about the order of evaluation, but do not know how to solve.

Or, any other easy methods to achieve my goal?

Comment: Try `SetAttributes[tablesaveFunction, HoldAll]`.

Comment: Same result....

Comment: Look up `DumpSave` in the documentation (and on this site)...

Comment: `Remove[tablesaveFunction];  SetAttributes[tablesaveFunction, HoldAll]; tablesaveFunction[x_] := Export[ToString@#1 <> ".dat", #2] &@@x;` works for me, but you end up writing the table with the head `HoldForm` which may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a `Hold` attribute for your function, as @N.J.Evans mentioned as well. Also, instead of using `Trace` to obtain the symbol name, try using `SymbolName` instead:

```
Clear[exportTable]

SetAttributes[exportTable, HoldFirst]
exportTable[t_] := Export[SymbolName[Unevaluated[t]] <> ".dat", t]

exportTable[table1]
```

You can then re-import your table at will:

```
Import["table1.dat"]
(* Out: {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

Comment: This works, though I may use DumpSave, thanks to @MikeLimaOscar

Comment: @Chromatic I think `DumpSave` would indeed be a good idea especially if your tables are massive. Nevertheless, it's probably still better to use the `SymbolName` approach, rather than `Trace`, to get to the symbol's name.

Comment: @Chromatic, if you think that my answer above adequately addresses your problem, would you consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting with the symbol `table1` and trying to extract the name of it and convert it to a string, why not give the string as the function argument and use `ToExpression` inside the function to access the variable?

```
exportTable[s_String] := Export[s <> ".dat", ToExpression@s]
```

You call this with a string with the same name as the table you want to export:

```
exportTable["table1"]
```